# Can this code be realigned?

Tags: javascript

I have this code for a falling petal effect. The original code is not mine, I know nothing about coding beyond how to maybe change a few things like image (as I've done with this version of the code), but I'm wondering if it's possible to make it appear to fall on only the left side of the page.

I'm extremely ignorant to this sort of thing, I've tried looking for an answer but I'm not even sure *how* to ask the question, so my best hope is that someone will understand what I'm looking for and be able to answer. I've played with it a little, but other than figuring out how to change the fall speed, I don't know if I'll be able to do it just fiddling. I am a little afraid it'd need to be completely re-written but for now, any help would be appreciated. (Original code is still credited and links back to the original on the tutorial blog it came from, I've removed it as it's not relevant to this question but can provide it if needed for whatever reason).

```
<script>if(typeof jQuery=='undefined'){document.write('<'+'script');document.write(' language="javascript"');document.write(' type="text/javascript"');document.write(' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">');document.write('</'+'script'+'>')}</script><script>if(!image_urls){var image_urls=Array()}if(!flash_urls){var flash_urls=Array()}image_urls['rain1']="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LVX2LSAy4zM/VuyuSSQGKoI/AAAAAAAAAHk/0xFc8xRWzh8rUrbWaxkLaXFiSM6D46fiA/s1600/imageedit_2_9597694661.png";image_urls['rain2']="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LVX2LSAy4zM/VuyuSSQGKoI/AAAAAAAAAHk/0xFc8xRWzh8rUrbWaxkLaXFiSM6D46fiA/s1600/imageedit_2_9597694661.png";image_urls['rain3']="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LVX2LSAy4zM/VuyuSSQGKoI/AAAAAAAAAHk/0xFc8xRWzh8rUrbWaxkLaXFiSM6D46fiA/s1600/imageedit_2_9597694661.png";image_urls['rain4']="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LVX2LSAy4zM/VuyuSSQGKoI/AAAAAAAAAHk/0xFc8xRWzh8rUrbWaxkLaXFiSM6D46fiA/s1600/imageedit_2_9597694661.png";$(document).ready(function(){var c=$(window).width();var d=$(window).height();var e=function(a,b){return Math.round(a+(Math.random()*(b-a)))};var f=function(a){setTimeout(function(){a.css({left:e(0,c)+'px',top:'-30px',display:'block',opacity:'0.'+e(10,100)}).animate({top:(d-10)+'px'},e(7500,8000),function(){$(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){f(a)})})},e(1,8000))};$('<div></div>').attr('id','rainDiv')
.css({position:'fixed',width:(c-20)+'px',height:'1px',left:'0px',top:'-5px',display:'block'}).appendTo('body');for(var i=1;i<=20;i++){var g=$('<img/>').attr('src',image_urls['rain'+e(1,4)])
.css({position:'absolute',left:e(0,c)+'px',top:'-30px',display:'block',opacity:'0.'+e(10,100),'margin-left':0}).addClass('rainDrop').appendTo('#rainDiv');f(g);g=null};var h=0;var j=0;$(window).resize(function(){c=$(window).width();d=$(window).height()})});</script>
```

Comment: Where did you find the code for this effect?

Comment: http://tutorialuntukblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/tutorial-kelopak-bunga-berguguran-di.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, you should check with the code's author if he's ok with people modifying and reusing his code. He might even give you the solution to your problem.

---

Change `left: e(0,c) + 'px'` to `left: e(0, c/2) + 'px'` inside the `setTimeout()` call.
`e` is a `random(startRange, endRange)` function and `c` is the window's length, so by halving the possible positions from the left of the window where the rain drop can appear, we effectively restrict them to the left half of the screen.

Here is a [fiddle illustrating the change](https://jsfiddle.net/gtce22dm/2/).

Note that I haven't bothered to understand the whole script, and that there are two other references to `c` that you might have to check (maybe for older browsers compatibility?) :

- the size of the `rainDiv` is `c - 20` px. This likely does not matter in recent browsers, or even at all
- the for loop looks like it's supposed to create rain drops at the start of the script, but I haven't seen it change anything. It also uses a random `e(0, c)`.

Comment: thank you, I will certainly keep trying to contact the author of the code. It was made back in 2011 I believe, so so far no luck in getting a reply, but thank you for the help, it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
http://jsbeautifier.org/

Example of your code with  beautifier:

```
<script>
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write('<' + 'script');
    document.write(' language="javascript"');
    document.write(' type="text/javascript"');
    document.write(' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">');
    document.write('</' + 'script' + '>')
}
</script>

<script>
if (!image_urls) {
    var image_urls = Array()
}
if (!flash_urls) {
    var flash_urls = Array()
}
image_urls['rain1'] = "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LVX2LSAy4zM/VuyuSSQGKoI/AAAAAAAAAHk/0xFc8xRWzh8rUrbWaxkLaXFiSM6D46fiA/s1600/imageedit_2_9597694661.png";
image_urls['rain2'] = "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LVX2LSAy4zM/VuyuSSQGKoI/AAAAAAAAAHk/0xFc8xRWzh8rUrbWaxkLaXFiSM6D46fiA/s1600/imageedit_2_9597694661.png";
image_urls['rain3'] = "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LVX2LSAy4zM/VuyuSSQGKoI/AAAAAAAAAHk/0xFc8xRWzh8rUrbWaxkLaXFiSM6D46fiA/s1600/imageedit_2_9597694661.png";
image_urls['rain4'] = "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LVX2LSAy4zM/VuyuSSQGKoI/AAAAAAAAAHk/0xFc8xRWzh8rUrbWaxkLaXFiSM6D46fiA/s1600/imageedit_2_9597694661.png";
$(document).ready(function() {
    var c = $(window).width();
    var d = $(window).height();
    var e = function(a, b) {
        return Math.round(a + (Math.random() * (b - a)))
    };
    var f = function(a) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            a.css({
                left: e(0, c) + 'px',
                top: '-30px',
                display: 'block',
                opacity: '0.' + e(10, 100)
            }).animate({
                top: (d - 10) + 'px'
            }, e(7500, 8000), function() {
                $(this).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    f(a)
                })
            })
        }, e(1, 8000))
    };
    $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'rainDiv')
        .css({
            position: 'fixed',
            width: (c - 20) + 'px',
            height: '1px',
            left: '0px',
            top: '-5px',
            display: 'block'
        }).appendTo('body');
    for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        var g = $('<img/>').attr('src', image_urls['rain' + e(1, 4)])
            .css({
                position: 'absolute',
                left: e(0, c) + 'px',
                top: '-30px',
                display: 'block',
                opacity: '0.' + e(10, 100),
                'margin-left': 0
            }).addClass('rainDrop').appendTo('#rainDiv');
        f(g);
        g = null
    };
    var h = 0;
    var j = 0;
    $(window).resize(function() {
        c = $(window).width();
        d = $(window).height()
    })
});
</script>
```